# Pushing to Git from webstorm

Tags: git, webstorm

I'm looking for alternatives to use Git on Windows. Git Gui is to complex for our developers, they used to work with subversion (assembla) using tortois, and committed very easily. Now we are moving to Git with BitBucket, and I'm looking for a normal client via WebStorm.
There's no hint in their documentaion on how to actually link the local repo to the remote repo. (http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/webhelp/using-git-integration.html)

Does anybody know of a way to integrate between this two? Better yet, maybe there's a better client then Git Gui?

Thanks

UPDATE ---

Just using TortoiseGit and that's it.

Comment: You need to manually add the **remote** into `.git/config` file. Then you'll be able to push into it from WebStorm and command line. Another approach is [described in the documentation](http://wiki.jetbrains.net/intellij/Using_Git_Locally#Uploading_the_Master_Branch_to_a_Remote_Repository).

Comment: Hey, I added the remote command to the file and "pushed" it via the ide without any errors, but I can't see anything in BitBucket.

Comment: `git remote add origin http://example.com/myRepo/`. Should not be to complex :) Beside this: Know your tools! :p (Tell that you devs :D)

Answer (score 4):

I've found that Source Tree is the one Git GUI app that team members actually enjoy using: http://www.sourcetreeapp.com/

It's for both Windows and Mac.

Comment: Cool client, but tooooooo stupid. On mac people say it's ok. But i have used it on windows, and if you have a couple of repo, some of them are big. It's toooo slow. Just click on any branch and wait for a minute, or any commit. Just click, then you have yo push it ))))

Found that webstorm IDE it's enough, there is commits tree view as well, click on LOG to see the tree. 

Actually easy as i don't knwo what ) ctrl + T to get all changes from remote, ctrl + K -> commit, ctrl + shift + K, push all to origin. 

And you don't need to open that stupid source tree.

Comment: Source tree could be slow depend on version + git cli version, but i used to update both periodically and it was keeping to be stupid. If you have one small project than it would be ok.

Comment: And yep i have new top laptop. Intel Core i7, 8 ram etc. And 16gb + slower processor Desctop at office, Sourse Tree was slow on both.

Comment: I agree that it's really slow on Windows with big repos. But so are a lot of other tools. Especially if you have deep nested structures like /node_modules. That can even trip up the native file system explorer. EDIT: I'm not advocating putting /node_modules in git btw.! ;)

Comment: I put node_modules bower_components to git ignore always, don't think it should does any impact. Actually i started to use webstorm for the same repos and it works like a charm while Source Tree is creeping.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the bitbucket plugin, try one of these options

1) https://bitbucket.org/dmitry_cherkas/jetbrains-bitbucket-connector/overview
2) http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6207?pr=ruby

I have personally gone with the first version, and sofar it's working just fine.